# I can't click on the buttons

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making a sales system, and in the area where the total sums are described, I can't  click on the buttons.

I tried to remove buttons from the gridpane and they work for me but when I integrate them into the gridpane they lose focus or stop working

```
Pane root = new Pane();

Separator top = new Separator(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
top.setPrefWidth(1310);

Separator left = new Separator(Orientation.VERTICAL);
left.setPrefHeight(150);

left.setPadding(new Insets(0,0,10,0));
Separator low = new Separator(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

low.setPadding(new Insets(140,10,0,0));
low.setPrefWidth(1323);

Separator right = new Separator(Orientation.VERTICAL);
right.setPrefHeight(150);

right.setPadding(new Insets(0,0,10,1310));


Label descuento = new Label("Descuento: ");

Label sub = new Label("Sub-Total: ");

Label iva = new Label("Iva: ");

Label total = new Label("Total: ");

Label rsub = new Label("0000.00");

Label riva= new Label("16%");

Label rtotal = new Label("0.0000");


Button btn_generate = new Button("generate");

MenuItem opc = new MenuItem("Opc");
MenuItem opc1= new MenuItem("opc1");

MenuButton menu1 = new MenuButton("Type",null,opc,opc1);

MenuItem opc2 = new MenuItem("opc2");
MenuItem opc3 = new MenuItem("opc3");

MenuButton menu2 = new MenuButton("Opc",null,opc2,opc3);


GridPane Gtotal = new GridPane();

Gtotal.setHgap(20);
Gtotal.setVgap(10);
Gtotal.setPadding(new Insets(10,0,0,10));

ColumnConstraints column1 = new ColumnConstraints(rtotal.getPrefWidth(),rtotal.getPrefWidth(),rtotal.getPrefWidth());
ColumnConstraints column2 = new ColumnConstraints(total.getPrefWidth()+450,total.getPrefWidth()+450,total.getPrefWidth()+450);
ColumnConstraints column3 = new ColumnConstraints(riva.getPrefWidth(),riva.getPrefWidth(),riva.getPrefWidth());
ColumnConstraints column4 = new ColumnConstraints(iva.getPrefWidth()+330,iva.getPrefWidth()+330,iva.getPrefWidth()+330);
ColumnConstraints column5 = new ColumnConstraints(rsub.getPrefWidth(),rsub.getPrefWidth(),rsub.getPrefWidth());
ColumnConstraints column6 = new ColumnConstraints(sub.getPrefWidth(),sub.getPrefWidth(),sub.getPrefWidth());

Gtotal.getColumnConstraints().add(0,column1);
Gtotal.getColumnConstraints().add(0,column2);
Gtotal.getColumnConstraints().add(0,column3);
Gtotal.getColumnConstraints().add(0,column4);
Gtotal.getColumnConstraints().add(0,column5);
Gtotal.getColumnConstraints().add(0,column6);

GridPane.setConstraints(descuento, 0, 0);
GridPane.setConstraints(menu1, 1, 0);
GridPane.setConstraints(menu2, 2, 0);
GridPane.setConstraints(sub, 0, 1);
GridPane.setConstraints(rsub, 1, 1);

GridPane.setConstraints(iva, 2, 1);
GridPane.setHalignment(iva, HPos.RIGHT);

GridPane.setConstraints(riva, 3, 1);

GridPane.setConstraints(total, 4, 1);
GridPane.setHalignment(total, HPos.RIGHT);

GridPane.setConstraints(rtotal, 5, 1);
GridPane.setConstraints(btn_generate, 5, 2);

Gtotal.getChildren().addAll(descuento,sub,rsub,iva,riva,total,rtotal,btn_generate,menu1,menu2);

root.getChildren().addAll(top,left,Gtotal,low,right);

Scene scene = new Scene(root);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

I hope that when running the program I can click on the buttons.

Comment: Which TextFields? I only see Labels.

Comment: ya corregi in my question, but in the same code if I try to add textfield does not allow me to write in the

Comment: Separators are the issue. Your separators and Gridpane were overlapping. Set it to a smaller value or increase your pane size.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a [mcve] ?

Comment: The separators were indeed the problem, I changed the way to locate it and it worked. thank you.

Comment: Instead of using padding to adjust separators position use VBox and Hbox. In HBox put **right, GTotal and left** and for VBox put **top, HBox, and low**.

Comment: @MarcosAntonio Here is a link http://tutorials.jenkov.com/javafx/gridpane.html But I have a question are you using Scene Builder to do your user interface layout? And do you know how code a onActionEvent for a Button?

Comment: @Grendel I'm not using the scene builder, I'm designing to pure code.

Answer (score 0):

Marcos Antonio You are really making work for yourself not using Scene Builder
That said here is 3 lines of code that make a button fire an event

```
    Button btnOK = new Button("OK");
    btnOK.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION,filter);
    btnOK.setOnAction((ActionEvent evt) -> {
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the separators that overlapped the other layout by the padding